# save an avatar in octobercms database after i modified it

Tags: laravel, octobercms

after resizing the user avatar with intervention image ,i try to store it in the octobercms database like this code:

```
        if (Input::hasFile('avatar')) {


    $file= Input::file('avatar');

  $filenamewithextension =   $file->getClientOriginalName();


   //get filename without extension
           $filename = pathinfo($filenamewithextension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);


  //get file extension
      $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();


   //filename to store
           $filenametostore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;





            Storage::put('public/profile_images/'. $filenametostore, fopen($file, 'r+'));
            Storage::put('public/profile_images/thumbnail/'. $filenametostore, fopen($file, 'r+'));



    //Resize image here
           $thumbnailpath ='storage/app/public/profile_images/thumbnail/'.$filenametostore;


             $img = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
             $img->crop(request('w'), request('h'), request('x1'), request('y1'));


      $img->save($thumbnailpath);

        $user->avatar=  $filenametostore;


        }
```

i get this error:

```
The avatar must be an image.
C:\wamp643\www\october3\vendor\october\rain\src\Database\Traits\Validation.php line 340
```

i really don't know what to do ,i'm a beginner.

please help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are just setting file name you should set full path of image there.

> Assuming you have already `avatar` attachment relation in user model

```
public $attachOne = [
    'avatar' => ['System\Models\File']
];
```

> replace

```
$user->avatar = $filenametostore;
```

> with

```
$user->avatar = storage_path($thumbnailpath);
```

may be it should work.

if doubt please comment.

Comment: thank you very much but the problem is the same
Nothing has changed

Comment: can you share `dd($user->avatar);` info after assignment, and where do you writing this code.

Comment: this is the result of dd($user->avatar)  :`images (3)_1540464305.jpg`  . and for the palce of the code: ** RainLab\User\Components\account.php**

Comment: `$user->avatar=$thumbnailpath;    dd($user->avatar);` desplay this: `"storage/app/public/profile_images/thumbnail/images (2)_1540466712.jpg"`

Comment: ok may be you forget to add `storage_path()`, in answer its `$user->avatar = storage_path($thumbnailpath);` so your path would be from root, may be i updated it you used it before i updated , i guess

Comment: I test a something:  ` $user->avatar= Input::file('avatar');
        dd($user->avatar);

`and i get this :   `UploadedFile {#596 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "images (3).jpg"
  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
  -size: 9300
 }`

Comment: yes it's fine but that image will not be croped i guess, can you try this one `$user->avatar = storage_path($thumbnailpath);` => `$user->avatar` need full path OR `file` instance

Comment: i think $user->avatar only accept an object like I showed you Input::file('avatar') so i need a way to convert  the image on a file like the file_ object; i have test storage_path but stil the same problem

Comment: check this one : https://octobercms.com/docs/database/attachments#creating-attachments from official document, just try it if it not work we can use something else

Comment: if i write this :  `$thumbnailpath ='C:wamp643/www/october3/storage/app/public/profile_images/thumbnail/'.$filenametostore` i get the same error as first: **The avatar must be an image**

Comment: i think i need a way to convert the result on  **file-instance** like you sayed

Comment: your path is wrong : ''C:wamp643/www' <= you need to add `'C:/wamp643/www` - or just better use `storage_path` as it normalize path with propr `directory separator`

Comment: i did just like you sayed but nothing happend same issue

Comment: to convert file-instace you can use `fromFile($filePath)` but again it will need path, same as here `$file = new System\Models\File;
$file->fromFile('/path/to/avatar.jpg');` so i guess some thing is missing, i will check in my local by reproducing this

Comment: you are using this lib `http://image.intervention.io/api/make` to `crop` image right?

Comment: look what i did : `$file = new System\Models\File;
                            $file->fromFile($thumbnailpath);                                          
                             $user->avatar=$file`                                                         but i get this:         **Class 'RainLab\User\Components\System\Models\File' not found**

Comment: hello are you still there

Comment: good news sir ,i have resolved it :$file = new \System\Models\File as you've sayed yesterday just i add \

Comment: so thank you very much for your help it was very intersting